# Why full-text-search returns less rows than LIKE

Tags: mysql, myisam, full-text-search

I don't get full-text-search working as I want it to, and I don't understand the differences in the resultlists.
Example statements:

```
SELECT `meldungstext`
FROM `artikel`
WHERE `meldungstext` LIKE '%punkt%'
```

returns 92 rows. I receive rows which have matches, for example, like "Punkten", "Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung" and "Treffpunkt" in column meldungstext.

I set a fulltext-index on the column "meldungstext" and tried this:

```
SELECT `meldungstext`
FROM `artikel`
WHERE MATCH (`meldungstext`)
AGAINST ('*punkt*')
```

this returns only 8 rows. I receive only rows which have matches to "Punkt" itself or words which I think are taken as "Punkt" as in "i-Punkt".

I then tried boolean mode:

```
SELECT `meldungstext`
FROM `artikel`
WHERE MATCH (`meldungstext`)
AGAINST ('*punkt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

returns 44 rows. I receive rows which have "Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung" or "Treffpunkt" in column meldungstext, but not those with "Punkten".

Why does this happen and how can I set a "fully" working full-text-search to prevent using LIKE '%%' in the where-clause?

Comment: This deserves a big +1 because this issue is not really examined and FULLTEXT indexing is often taken for granted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took the three strings in your question and added it to a table plus three more string with `pankt` instead of `punkt`.

The following was executed using MySQL 5.5.12 for Windows

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE artikel
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     meldungstext MEDIUMTEXT,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ->     FULLTEXT (meldungstext)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO artikel (meldungstext) VALUES
    -> ('Punkten'),('Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung'),('Treffpunkt'),
    -> ('Pankten'),('Zwei-Pankte-Vorsprung'),('Treffpankt');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

I ran these queries against the table using 3 different approaches

- `MATCH ... AGAINST`
- `LOCATE` as in the [**LOCATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function
- `LIKE`

Please note the differences

```
mysql> SELECT id,meldungstext,
    -> COUNT(IF(MATCH (`meldungstext`) AGAINST ('*punkt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE),1,0)) PunktMatch,
    -> IF(LOCATE('punkt',meldungstext)>0,1,0) PunktLocate,
    -> meldungstext  LIKE '%punkt%' PunktLike
    -> FROM `artikel` GROUP BY id,meldungstext;
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | meldungstext          | PunktMatch | PunktLocate | PunktLike |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Punkten               |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  2 | Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  3 | Treffpunkt            |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  4 | Pankten               |          1 |           0 |         0 |
|  5 | Zwei-Pankte-Vorsprung |          1 |           0 |         0 |
|  6 | Treffpankt            |          1 |           0 |         0 |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

All the PunktMatch values should bee 3 1's and 3 0's.

Now watch me query them as normal

```
mysql> SELECT `meldungstext` FROM `artikel`
    -> WHERE MATCH (`meldungstext`) AGAINST ('*punkt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-----------------------+
| meldungstext          |
+-----------------------+
| Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |
| Punkten               |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT `meldungstext` FROM `artikel`
    -> WHERE LOCATE('punkt',meldungstext)>0;
+-----------------------+
| meldungstext          |
+-----------------------+
| Punkten               |
| Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |
| Treffpunkt            |
+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `meldungstext` FROM `artikel`
    -> WHERE `meldungstext` LIKE '%punk%';
+-----------------------+
| meldungstext          |
+-----------------------+
| Punkten               |
| Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |
| Treffpunkt            |
+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK using MATCH .. AGAINST with punkt does not work. What about pankt ???

```
mysql> SELECT `meldungstext` FROM `artikel` WHERE `meldungstext` LIKE '%pankt%';
+-----------------------+
| meldungstext          |
+-----------------------+
| Pankten               |
| Zwei-Pankte-Vorsprung |
| Treffpankt            |
+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's run my big `GROUP BY` query against pankt

```
mysql> SELECT id,meldungstext,
    -> COUNT(IF(MATCH (`meldungstext`) AGAINST ('*pankt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE),1,0)) PanktMatch,
    -> IF(LOCATE('pankt',meldungstext)>0,1,0) PanktLocate,
    -> meldungstext  LIKE '%pankt%' PanktLike
    -> FROM `artikel` GROUP BY id,meldungstext;
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | meldungstext          | PanktMatch | PanktLocate | PanktLike |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Punkten               |          1 |           0 |         0 |
|  2 | Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |          1 |           0 |         0 |
|  3 | Treffpunkt            |          1 |           0 |         0 |
|  4 | Pankten               |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  5 | Zwei-Pankte-Vorsprung |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  6 | Treffpankt            |          1 |           1 |         1 |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

This is wrong also because I should see 3 0's and 3 1's for PanktMatch.

I tried something else

```
mysql> SELECT id,meldungstext, MATCH (`meldungstext`) AGAINST ('+*pankt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) PanktMatch, IF(LOCATE('pankt',meldungstext)>0,1,0) PanktLocate, meldungstext  LIKE '%pankt%' PanktLike FROM `artikel` GROUP BY id,meldungstext;
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | meldungstext          | PanktMatch | PanktLocate | PanktLike |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Punkten               |          0 |           0 |         0 |
|  2 | Zwei-Punkte-Vorsprung |          0 |           0 |         0 |
|  3 | Treffpunkt            |          0 |           0 |         0 |
|  4 | Pankten               |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  5 | Zwei-Pankte-Vorsprung |          1 |           1 |         1 |
|  6 | Treffpankt            |          0 |           1 |         1 |
+----+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I added a plus sign to pankt and I got different results. What 2 and not 3 ???

According to the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), notice what it says about the wildcard character:

> *
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it should be appended to the word to be affected.
>   Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.
>
> If a word is specified with the truncation operator, it is not
>   stripped from a boolean query, even if it is too short (as determined
>   from the ft_min_word_len setting) or a stopword. This occurs because
>   the word is not seen as too short or a stopword, but as a prefix that
>   must be present in the document in the form of a word that begins with
>   the prefix. Suppose that ft_min_word_len=4. Then a search for '+word
>   +the*' will likely return fewer rows than a search for '+word +the':
>
> The former query remains as is and requires both word and the* (a word
>   starting with the) to be present in the document.
>
> The latter query is transformed to +word (requiring only word to be
>   present). the is both too short and a stopword, and either condition
>   is enough to cause it to be ignored.

Based on this, the wildcard character is applicable for the back of tokens and not for the front. In light of this, the output must be correct because 2 of the 3 punkt's start tokens. Same story with pankt. This at least explains why 2 out of 3 and why less rows.

Comment: Wow, many thanks for your investment. This means full-text-search works as espected, or at least as said in the docu. But this also states that the whole full-text-issue won't help to find 100% of columns which include a given word-part, which makes it useless for my purposes. For exact results I'd need to search with LIKE or LOCALE, which besides surprisingly both seem to be faster.

Comment: Why did you find "Punkten" and @32bitfloat did not?! Instead he found "Treffpunkt", but you did not. And I do not really understand why "punkt" returned "Pankten" in the `COUNT(IF(MATCH` query.

Comment: I wonder what happens in InnoDB.

Comment: Why do you have `COUNT(…)` on the PunktMatch and PanktMatch columns? `COUNT(IF(MATCH (`meldungstext`) AGAINST ('*pankt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE),1,0))` will _always_ result in `1`, because it is counting `1` or `0`, the result from the `IF(…)`.