# Will moving the MATCH...AGAINST part in different part of the query (e.g. before evaluation of JOIN) will improve the performance?

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, full-text-search

Basically, I have the following query:

```
select `t`.*
from `tracking` `t` 
where exists 
(   
    select `ti`.`id` from `tracking_items` `ti`
    inner join `cars` `c` on (`c`.`car_id` = `ti`.`tracking_object_id`)
    where `t`.`id` = `ti`.`tracking_id` and match(`c`.`car_text`) against('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode) 
    limit 1
) and ... limit 5
```

**The problem I have?**

There's `FULLTEXT` index for `c.car_text` column, but however the query is running a bit slowly (especially for records that rarely occurs, e.g. searching for non-existing keyword).

I haven't published the result of `EXPLAIN`, as I'd like to know the theory behind my question, e.g. for different possible cases.

I use MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB storage engine, also it's worth to mention that `cars` table have like ~160m records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad you came here. I have always suggested using FULLTEXT indexes to collect keys first and then join it to other tables.

- `Oct 25, 2011` : [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Jul 18, 2012` : [Why full-text-search returns less rows than LIKE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21118/why-full-text-search-returns-less-rows-than-like/21128#21128)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)
- `Jan 29, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `Aug 01, 2016` : [How to make a FULLTEXT search with ORDER BY fast?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145490/how-to-make-a-fulltext-search-with-order-by-fast/145558#145558)

In your particular case, I would suggest rewriting your query as an all-out JOIN:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tracking t
INNER JOIN tracking_items ti ON t.id = ti.tracking_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT car_id,car_text FROM cars WHERE MATCH(car_text)
AGAINST ('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode)) c
ON ti.tracking_object_id = c.car_id LIMIT 5;
```

or maybe

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT car_id,car_text FROM cars WHERE MATCH(car_text)
AGAINST ('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode)) c
INNER JOIN tracking_items ti ON c.car_id = ti.tracking_object_id
INNER JOIN tracking t ON ti.tracking_id = t.id  LIMIT 5;
```

If these queries give you an idea, please incorporate it if you still want to use `WHERE EXISTS`.

Please run the explain plan on these queries and your and see the differences

```
EXPLAIN select `t`.*
from `tracking` `t` 
where exists 
(   
    select `ti`.`id` from `tracking_items` `ti`
    inner join `cars` `c` on (`c`.`car_id` = `ti`.`tracking_object_id`)
    where `t`.`id` = `ti`.`tracking_id` and match(`c`.`car_text`)
    against('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode) 
    limit 1
) and ... limit 5;

EXPLAIN SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT car_id,car_text FROM cars WHERE MATCH(car_text)
AGAINST ('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode)) c
INNER JOIN tracking_items ti ON c.car_id = ti.tracking_object_id
INNER JOIN tracking t ON ti.tracking_id = t.id LIMIT 5;

EXPLAIN SELECT t.* FROM tracking t
INNER JOIN tracking_items ti ON t.id = ti.tracking_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT car_id,car_text FROM cars WHERE MATCH(car_text)
AGAINST ('+bulgaria +turkey' in boolean mode)) c
ON ti.tracking_object_id = c.car_id LIMIT 5;
```

Give it a try, and let us know what happens !!!

Comment: Thanks! The query you suggested is executed pretty quickly! However, I need `WHERE EXISTS (...)`, because my idea is to "search" in multiple tables, and I'd like to `OR` them, starting from tables with "less" records. I'll try to find a way to incorporate your query with `WHERE EXISTS (...)` syntax and hopefully it will do the job.

Comment: Oh BTW, Welcome to the DBA StackExchange !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - The Question is about InnoDB FULLTEXT; do your old links apply to InnoDB?  I think not, since it was GA in 2013-02-05 5.6.10.  I have encountered numerous differences between the  implementations.

Answer (score 1):

That query is rather confusing.  You want one tracking_item, then fetch 5 trackings?  And you don't care which tracking_item (there is no `ORDER BY`).  And you apparently don't care which 5 trackings.

I suggest using `JOIN` instead of `EXISTS`.  The goal is to let `MATCH` be the first thing that happens.

```
SELECT t.*
    FROM (
        SELECT ti.tracking_id
            FROM cars AS c
            JOIN tracking_item AS ti  ON ti.tracking_object_id = c.car_id
            WHERE MATCH(c.car_text) AGAINST('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            ORDER BY ???
            LIMIT 1
         ) AS x
    JOIN tracking AS t  ON t.id = ti.tracking_id
    ORDER BY ???
    LIMIT 5
```

Now it reads in the same order that the Optimizer will (I expect) decide to do things.

1. Do the fulltext query on cars, delivering only a few, if any, rows;
2. Pick the first match (no `ORDER BY`) or fetch all that match, sort, and deliver first.
3. join to tracking_item to get the tracking_id(s)
4. Pick one tracking_id
5. Fetch 5 rows (if no `ORDER BY`) or all rows matching on `tracking_id` and sort them.
6. Deliver all columns for up to 5 rows.

Indexes needed:

```
tracking_item:  INDEX(tracking_object_id, tracking_id)  -- in this order
tracking:       INDEX(id)  -- (not needed if it is already the PRIMARY KEY)
```

As for the question in the title -- It is much too broad to give a yes/no answer.  There could be many different extenuating circumstances.